How to get name and symbol of token from mint address
Im using javascript and i have the mint address of a token, for example this "Ei71196o8MpDsVdXyZEewEdxP4A8n3KMZKTFE7KE2xTR" and i want to get the name which in this case is Sillybird and the symbol which is SIB.
I have searched throught here and only found 1 @solana\web3.js example which didnt give me the name nor symbol, and some metaplex examples that didnt work at all.
I would appreciate any help

I think using DAS is the best way. You can use Helius to do this. You will need to get a free API key by signing up, then paste it in the "API Key" part.
(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=<API Key>', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "id": "text",
            "method": "getAsset",
            "params": { id: 'Ei71196o8MpDsVdXyZEewEdxP4A8n3KMZKTFE7KE2xTR'}
        }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(`name = ${data.result.content.metadata.name}`);
    console.log(`symbol = ${data.result.content.metadata.symbol}`);
})();

Result:
name = Sillybird
symbol = SIB



